# Create a new model in Django linked tothe User table

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I've correctly created my first web app where I can register and login as an user. I'm using the standard `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and `UserCreationForm`to manage this thing.

Now, I would like to create a new table in the database to add new fields to the user. I'm already using the standard one such as email, first name, second name, email, username, etc but I would like to extend it by adding the possibility to store the latest time the email has been changed and other info. All those info are not added via the form but are computed by the backend (for instance, every time I want to edit my email on my profile, the relative field on my new table, linked to my profile, change value)

To do that I have added on my `models.py` file the current code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAddInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_time_email_change = models.TimeField('Last email changed', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And on my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import UserAddInformation

admin.site.register(UserAddInformation)
```

The form to edit the email and the view can be found below

### forms.py

```
class EditUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = User

        # select the fields that you want to display
        fields = ('email',)
```

### views.py

```
@authenticated_user
def account_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user_info_obj = UserAddInformation.objects.create(user=request.user,
                                                              last_time_email_change=datetime.now())
            user_info_obj.save()
            messages.success(request, "Edit Succesfully")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        form = EditUserForm()
    return render(request, 'authenticate/account.html', {
        'form_edit': form,
    })
```

The issue is that, once I'm going to update the email via the form, I got an error ***UNIQUE constraint failed: members_useraddinformation.user_id***

Using `ForeignKey` make it works but it create a new row in the table, with the same when I just want to update the first one

The edit process for the email works tho

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `auto_now_add=True` inherit `editable=False` generating the error. So changing my ***models.py*** with

```
class UserAddInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_time_email_change = models.TimeField('Last email changed')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.last_time_email_change = timezone.now()
        return super(UserAddInformation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and checking with

```
user_info_obj = UserAddInformation.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
user_info_obj[0].save()
```

inside `def account_user(request):` worked

I'm not sure it's the best solution for my issue tho